# Sending a keystroke to a different process in java

Tags: java

I wrote a small program that presses keys and releases them.

The problem that occured was that the keys are not pressed in the process where I was trying to run it in. Lets say I tried running it in a `game(.exe)` and not in a browser or a folder.

My question is: Is there an option in Java to send keystrokes to a different, non-Java process?

Comment: Any returned value can be consumed but interoperability is a question. so as an example shell scripts can read the keyboard presses. If you are writing the character in the same location predefined for the keyboard then it should not be a problem.

Comment: You have to hook your program to the process you want to target. It's not easy to do and there's not much information to find, but there is no other way (as far as I know).